# C# Random Number Gen stops after 12 button clicks

Tags: c#, random

Working on homework assignment and random number generator stops populating TestBox after 12 button clicks?? This happens every single time I run it and I have no idea why. Also if anything looks sloppy please say so.

```
public partial class GuessANumber : Form
{
    int[] array = new int[100];
    public GuessANumber()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        array = RandomArray();
        this.Gen_Rand.Click += new EventHandler(this.Gen_Rand_Click);
    }

    public int[] RandomArray()
    {            
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rand.Next(1, 100);
        }
        return array;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}

    private void Gen_Rand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        array = RandomArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            TestBox.AppendText(" " + Convert.ToString(array[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make textbox smaller and it will start happening earlier. Or larger...

Comment: Since you've asked for it: your design `RandomArray` is very strange. First of all, you're assigning values to array, index by index, then you return the array and use returned value to set the array. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: `code`        private void Gen_Rand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestBox.Clear();
            //array = RandomArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                TestBox.AppendText(" " + Convert.ToString(RandomArray()[i]));
            }
        }

Comment: What I wanted to say is make a generator function (preferably static), which will initialize new array, populate it with elements and return it. Or make it void and just set the values, without returning the array. Both at the same time makes it confusing when first reading it.

Comment: Sorry trying to format the code corectly

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
TestBox.AppendText(" " + Convert.ToString(array[i]));
```

you **append** more and more text to the `TextBox`. If the `TextBox` does not adjust its size or has scrollbars, you will not see the latest parts of the text.

Add something like

```
TestBox.Clear();
```

at the beginning of `Gen_Rand_Click()`